# C# simplewallet RPC calls

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, rpc, programming-languages

I'm quite new to cryptocurrencies, and I want to make a program that runs simplewallet (monero-wallet-cli) in the background as an RPC server and make calls to it using C#.
I already somewhat know how to start it as an RPC server ([per this bytecoin wiki link](https://wiki.bytecoin.org/wiki/Simplewallet_command_line_arguments_and_commands)), but how would I make calls to get information like the current balance and display it on the GUI, or make a transaction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should have a look at Monero's official [Wallet RPC documentation](https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/developer-guides/wallet-rpc). There's an example for each command.

**Update:** Those examples use the `curl` utility to send the HTTP request. The meaning of the parameters can be looked up in the [man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).

Comment: I understand, but what I'm confused about is how I actually call them. I see cUrl and I'm not sure how to do it in C#

Comment: `curl` is just a UNIX utility to send an HTTP request to a certain URL. I am not into C#, but I suppose there's an API to construct an HTTP request. In order to understand the meaning of those parameters, have a look at the [man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html). For example, `-X` is for the type of HTTP request, `-H` is for the HTTP header to be sent along, `-d` is for the data to be sent.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out. .Net has a simple way to send HTTP requests. Much love <3